# Preposition to use with “fall behind"

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

Which of the following sentences are correct?

> I’ve been falling behind **in** my work.
>
> I’ve been falling behind **with** my work.
>
> I’ve been falling behind **on** my work.

I’ve seen all three sentences written in different places, so I’ve gotten a bit confused. Are they all acceptable? Is any one preferable over the others?

Comment: Depends on the context and what noun occurs in the prepositional phrase. All three prepositions  are possible.

Comment: @Alan Carmack: Can you think of any contexts where any one of OP's three sentences would be either more or less appropriate than the alternatives? I can't.

Answer (score 1):

All three are grammatically correct, and all three could be understood without difficulty.

I would use "falling behind with" in this context. When speaking of an activty, use "with". Google gives some examples:

> In 1941 America was falling behind with wartime production schedules
>
> this child is suddenly falling behind with the academic work
>
> many people are falling behind with their mortgage payments

On the other hand use in when speaking of a place, perhaps metaphorically.

> Japan [...] is now falling behind in all areas.
>
> Torsten [...] is already falling behind in school.
>
> The UK is falling behind in treatment and scientific advances

Comment: Your last example "**The UK is falling behind in treatment and scientific advances**" is an activity.

Comment: Metaphorically, "treatment and scientific advances" is a region of medical practice, hence a metaphorical place. On the other hand, if a person were not taking their medicine regularly you would say that they were "falling behind with their treatment".